# How to send G Suite email securely with NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, email, security, environment-variables, nodemailer

I'm building a chatbot to automatically send email if an order is received.
I want the sender to be the company's email which has custom domain and G-Suite enabled.

Is there any way to do this securely?
If I use `nodemailer` and using the `.env` variable for the sender password and email, is it secure enough?
  Because I doubt putting password in someone else' server.

Comment: environment variables are commonly used to store secrets in production for lots of big firms. There are more secure options, but ultimately its about access. Who is root on the box you're deploying this to? If it is not you, then this is not secure. If anyone has access to the user this program is running under, then this is not secure. Ideally you deploy somewhere you completely control and only you have access to. Storing secrets in files can be secure, but if you get the file permissions wrong then other users on the box can read it.

Comment: @Catalyst I'm deploying it to Heroku.. Is it secure?
I just found out about `app password` by Gmail.. I never use it before and just know a thing or two about app password, so can I use it on my app and still stay secure?

 Or, is there any way to send email (GSuite) just by API so I don't need to tell the password (just the api key)?

Comment: you are probably fine on Heroku - they take steps to prevent cross-user contamination, and I doubt anyone could specifically target you even if that were the case, I can't get into GSuite console to see - but I would guess that you can send emails via api token.  If there isn't any API key in the console mentioned here - https://support.google.com/a/answer/60757?hl=en then have a look at the https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis to send via the gmail api. https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs

Comment: @Catalyst thanks for your answer. Anyway, I can't find anything about sending email (Gmail) in the npmjs docs, also at the quickstart docs. It seems that it's about auth, google drive, etc (i cant find about sending email)

Comment: Sorry for not pointing more directly check the JS sample from - https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send

Answer (score 0):

Hi First thing Nodemailer dont allow you to send Email using G-suite/Gmail or you can say that Gmail/Google dont allow to send it using username and password you need to use OAuth2 method to send email via gmail. 
for refrence: https://nodemailer.com/smtp/oauth2/

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
port: 465,
secure: true,
auth: {
    type: 'OAuth2',
    user: 'user@example.com',
    accessToken: 'ya29.Xx_XX0xxxxx-xX0X0XxXXxXxXXXxX0x'
}
});
```

Or

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
port: 465,
secure: true,
auth: {
    type: 'OAuth2',
    user: 'user@example.com'
}
});

transporter.set('oauth2_provision_cb', (user, renew, callback)=>{
let accessToken = userTokens[user];
if(!accessToken){
    return callback(new Error('Unknown user'));
}else{
    return callback(null, accessToken);
}
 });
```